# How to fetch the List items based on some blacklist

Tags: c#

i have an Blacklist int list

```
List<int> blackList = new List<int>(){1, 2, 3};
```

I have a collection which fetch some values from certain resource
`Dictionary<int,string> Sample=new Dictionary<int,string>()` . Dictionary have `{1,"data1"},{ 2,"data2"},{3,"data3"},{4,"data4"},{5,"data5"},{6,"data6"}` etc items;

based on the `blackList` how to fetch all items *except* blacklisted one.

I have tried the `Except` in Lambda expression .

my new Collection should have `{4,"data4"},{5,"data5"},{6,"data6"}`

Comment: `var result = source.Except(blackList);`

Comment: Your tried code please

Answer (score 1):

When querying try using Linq:

```
using System.Linq;
...

List<int> source = new List<int>()    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
List<int> blackList = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3};
```

If you want to obtain *distinct* items from `source`:

```
var result = source.Except(blackList);
```

If `source` can contain *duplicates* you want to preserve:

```
var result = source.Where(item => blackList.Contains(item));
```

In the second query, think over turning `blackList` into `HashSet<T>` which is more efficient (`O(1)` vs. `O(N)`) for `Contains`:

```
HashSet<int> blackList = new HashSet<int>() {1, 2, 3};
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. I have done small change to the question, can you please help me there? in the current secnario if i am using except, its showing some error .

'IGrouping<long, string>' does not contain a definition for 'Except' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Except<int>(IQueryable<int>, IEnumerable<int>)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<int>'

Comment: @lokanath das: so you don't have `List<int>` but some (RDBMS?) query. Now it depends on `IQueryable<T>`. As a quick patch - add `AsEnumerable<int>()`

Comment: Is it Var data= source.AsEnumerable().Where(x => blacklist.Except(x.id))

Its not working

Comment: `var data = source.AsEnumerable<int>().Where(x => blacklist.Except(x.id))` providing that `source` is `IQueryable<int>`

Comment: But source is List<int,string> (RDBMS data).

Comment: There is no such type - `List<int,string>`; you (probably) have `IQueryable<T>` with some `T`; if `T` is not `int` add `Select`: `source.Select(record => record.id /* depends on what you actually have */).AsEnumerable<int>()`

Comment: var abc = source.Select(x => x.id).Except(blacklist); 
var Final_Abc = source.Where(x => abc.Contains(x.id))

I got my expected result in Final_abc.

Answer (score 0):

Linq is great for stuff like this [linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/):

```
List<int> blackList = new List<int>(){1,2,3};

List<int> fullList = new List<int> {1,2,3,4,5,6};

var differences = fullList.Except(blackList);
```